# Solr fetch documents as CSV via cursor over HTTP

Tags: http, serialization, command-line, solr, export

Solr has a great [streaming feature](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/pagination-of-results.html#fetching-a-large-number-of-sorted-results-cursors) that allows to fetch large number documents quickly via cursors (e.g. [solrdump](https://github.com/ubleipzig/solrdump) allows to use this feature from the command line).

For these kind of cursor queries, it is possible to set the *wt*
 parameter as well to control the serialization, with the default being *xml* as of Solr 5.5.

```
$ curl -v "http://solr/select?cursorMark=*&fl=...&q=...&sort=id+asc&wt=json"
                                                                    -------
```

However, for the streaming queries to work, one must parse out the *nextCursorMark* from each response. With JSON and XML this is just another field, but with *wt* set to *csv* this information cannot be accommodated (at least not in the payload).

```
{
  ...
  },
  "nextCursorMark": "AoE4YWktNDgtUTAxRlgxODFNakU1TVRFeU1R"
}
```

My first thought was that *nextCursorMark* will probably sent in the HTTP header, but it seems it is not.

```
$ curl -v http://ex.index/solr/select?...wt=csv
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 00:04:25 GMT
< ETag: "ZTM2MDQ4MDAwMDAwMDAwMFNvbHI="
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
----8<---- body ----8<----
```

Is it possible to use this kind of query with the **CSV format**? I am curious, because I would expect slight performance wins, if both sender and receiver can just use CSV instead of JSON or XML.

Update:

It seems that there is some information (status, query time) already put into the header, in [SolrCore.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/929ce7ca30d5b4f9d08aee604ba5184f0d94d505/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/core/SolrCore.java#L2542-L2583). Maybe only used with [ADMIN](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/d6d2e3b2e30b600b9f550abf9414743d628cbcf0/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/servlet/HttpSolrCall.java#L714-L725), [also in V2](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/67a6a14302c159a46a5fc81e5e6e94643c288e99/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/api/V2HttpCall.java#L331) - [V2 docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/v2-api.html).

Comment: Benchmark the performance first - not sure if there's that much to be gained. Otherwise; I don't think there's cursorMark support over HTTP headers, but maybe a patch would be accepted

Comment: @MatsLindh, "not sure if there's that much to be gained" - yes, I don't suspect large gains, I was mostly curious about this slight gap in the API. SOLR could otherwise just 400 on the combination of "wt=csv" and "cursorMark".

Comment: There are many other features that doesn't make sense with the csv writer, so I don't think that will be a priority issue. The `/export` endpoint is intended for larger exports of result sets (as it can also stream the result set as it's being retrieved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see [in this thread](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/cursorMark-and-CSVResponseWriter-for-mass-reindex-td4283447.html), that feature is not supported. If you have some kind of unique id you can sort on, you can just roll your own cursorMark as explained there (still using wt=csv). I did it for a mass migration of close to a billion docs, worked perfectly.

Important caveat, index must not be being written to, or if it is:

1. the id you use should be only increasing for new docs (like a timestamp or sequence id in a db)
2. if not, you have to take care of any doc inserted after you started in a second pass (you will double process some docs probably)